# HELP: Integrating WP with raw PHP code once published button is hit

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions, publish

Hello guys let me just open up, I am not good in both Wp coding, I will like to integrate my wp site so that once the published/update button is hit, it will automatically import external mp3 file to my server and as well change the external mp3 link to the that is just imported to my server, however this has been done, here is the code I used though its a plugin.

```
class DX_Auto_Save_Images{

    function __construct(){     

        //filter and action hook
        add_filter( 'content_save_pre',array($this,'post_save_images') );   //save images
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'menu_page' ) );        //menu page
        add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', array( $this, 'remove_tmb' ) );    //remove tmb
        add_action( 'submitpost_box', array( $this, 'submit_box' ) );   //submit_box
        add_action( 'submitpage_box', array( $this, 'submit_box' ) );   //submit_box
    }



    //save post exterior images
    function post_save_images( $content ){
        if( ($_POST['save'] || $_POST['publish']) && ($_POST['DS_switch']!='not_save') ){
            set_time_limit(240);
            global $post;
            $post_id=$post->ID;
            $preg=preg_match_all('/<a.*?href="(.*?)"/',stripslashes($content),$matches);
            if($preg){
                $i = 1;
                foreach($matches[1] as $image_url){
                    if(empty($image_url)) continue;
                    $pos=strpos($image_url,get_bloginfo('url'));
                    if($pos===false){
                        $res=$this->save_images($image_url,$post_id,$i);
                        $replace=$res['url'];
                        $content=str_replace($image_url,$replace,$content);
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        remove_filter( 'content_save_pre', array( $this, 'post_save_images' ) );
        return $content;
    }



    //save exterior images
    function save_images($image_url,$post_id,$i){
        $file=file_get_contents($image_url);

                $_filter = true; // For the anonymous filter callback below.
add_filter( 'upload_dir', function( $arr ) use( &$_filter ){
    if ( $_filter ) {


         $arr['path'] = $arr['basedir'] . '/music' .$arr['subdir'];
        $arr['url'] = $arr['baseurl'] . '/music' .$arr['subdir'];



      //  $folder = '/org_logos'; // No trailing slash at the end.
      //  $arr['path'] .= $folder;
      // $arr['url'] .= $folder;
      // $arr['subdir'] .= $folder;




        /*THE BELOW IS FOR IS TO UPLOAD IT TO MUSIC CATEGORY WITHOUT YEAR AND MONTH BY ENTERMASTER. THIS SCRIPT IS WORKING FINE
        $arr['path'] = $arr['basedir'] . '/music';
        $arr['url'] = $arr['baseurl'] . '/music';
        $arr['subdir'] = '/music';
        */
    }

    return $arr;
} );

        $filename=basename($image_url);
        $options = get_option( 'dx-auto-save-images-options' );



        if( $options['chinese']=='yes' ){
          preg_match( '/(.*?)(\.\w+)$/', $filename, $match );
          $im_name = md5($match[1]).$match[2];      
        }
        else $im_name = $filename;
        $res=wp_upload_bits($im_name,'',$file);
    //  $res=wp_upload_bits($im_name,'',$file);
    //  $attach_id = $this->insert_attachment($res['file'],$post_id);
    //  if( $options['post-tmb']=='yes' && $i==1 ){
        //  set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
    //  }
        return $res;
        $_filter = false; // Disables the filter.
    }

    //insert attachment
    function insert_attachment($file,$id){
    //  $dirs=wp_upload_dir();
        $filetype=wp_check_filetype($file);
/*      $attachment=array(
        //  'guid'=>$dirs['baseurl'].'/music/'._wp_relative_upload_path($file),
            'post_mime_type'=>$filetype['type'],
            'post_title'=>preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/','',basename($file)),
            'post_content'=>'',
            'post_status'=>'inherit'
        ); */
    //  $attach_id=wp_insert_attachment($attachment,$file,$id);
    //  $attach_data=wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$file);
    //  wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$attach_data);
    //  return $attach_id;
    }

    //menu page
    function menu_page(){
        add_menu_page( 'DX-auto-save-mp3','Auto Import Mp3 File locally', 'manage_options', 'DX-auto-save-mp3', array( $this, 'options_form' ), plugins_url( 'icon.png', __FILE__ ) );
    }

    //options form
    function options_form(){
        $options = $this->save_options();
        include( 'options-form.php' );
    }

    //form bottom action
    function form_bottom(){
?>
    <div id="form-bottom" style="width:650px;border:1px dotted #ddd;background-color:#f7f7f7;padding:10px;margin-top:20px;">
        <p>For more coding by entermaster visit: <a href="https://www.gidiportal.com/" target="_blank">https://www.gidiportal.com</a></p>

    </div>  
<?php
    }

    //save options
    function save_options(){
        if( $_POST['submit'] ){
            $data=array(
                'tmb' => $_POST['tmb'],
                'chinese' => $_POST['chinese'],
                'switch' => $_POST['switch'],
                'post-tmb' => $_POST['post-tmb']
            );
            update_option( 'dx-auto-save-images-options', $data );
        }
        return get_option( 'dx-auto-save-images-options' );
    }

    //remove tmb
    function remove_tmb( $sizes ){
        $options = get_option( 'dx-auto-save-images-options' );
        if( $options['tmb']=='yes' ){
            $sizes = array();
        }
        return $sizes;
    }

    //get_sample_permalink_html
    function submit_box(  ){
        $options = get_option( 'dx-auto-save-images-options' );
        if( $options['switch'] == 'yes' ){
            echo '<span style="padding-bottom:5px;display:inline-block;"><input type="checkbox" name="DS_switch" value="not_save"/> 不保存远程图片.</span>';
        }
    }

}

//new
new DX_Auto_Save_Images();
```

Though I modified a plugin to get this result working.

Now i want to integrate this code to work with ID3 php music script i already have, so that i can be able to change both the album art, the title of the song and artiste name will just match exactly the one on the wp post title, then the imported external url in the wp content will pass through this php script once the publish button is hit it will just work on the back end and change the link on wordpress editor. here is the below php script, how ever the php part of the script it is working fine if i run it on browser, this is just the index of the script i want to integrate with wp to work together.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require ( 'getid3/getid3.php' ) ;

require ( 'getid3/join.php' ) ;


if( isset($_POST['submit'])){
$now = time() ;
$default_mp3_directory =  "../wp-content/uploads/music/";
$default_album = "Example.com";
$default_year = date("Y", $now);
$default_genre = "Example.com";
$default_producer = '';
$default_cover = './music.jpg';
$shownUrl = 'https://www.Example.com/wp-content/uploads/music/';
# To the real uploads

$mp3_filepath = trim($_POST['url']);
$mp3_songname = trim($_POST['title']);
$mp3_comment = "Downloaded from Example.com";;
$mp3_artist = trim($_POST['artiste']);
$artiste = $mp3_artist;
$pFilename = trim($_POST['filename']);
$mp3_filename = empty( $pFilename ) ? $mp3_artist.' - '.$mp3_songname : $pFilename;
$mp3_album = empty ( $_POST['album'] )  ? $default_album : trim ( $_POST['album'] );
$mp3_year = empty ( $_POST['year'] ) || !is_numeric($_POST['year']) || strlen($_POST['year']) != 4 ? $default_year : $_POST['year'];
$mp3_genre = empty ( $_POST['genre'] ) ? $default_genre : $_POST['genre'];
$extra = array ( 'year' => $mp3_year, 'genre' => trim($_POST['genre']), 'album' => trim($_POST['album']), 'producer' => ! empty ( $_POST['producer']) ? trim($_POST['producer']) : $default_producer );
$error = '';

# Checking the mp3

if( !filter_var($mp3_filepath, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
$error .= 'Invalid File URL<br>';
} else if ( empty($mp3_filename) OR empty ($mp3_songname) OR empty($mp3_artist)){
$error .= "Fields Marked * Are Required<br>";
} else if ( !file_exists($default_cover) ) {
$error .= 'The Photo Cover Has Not Been Uploaded';
} else {
$timeFolder .= date('Y', $now) . '/' . date('m', $now) . '/';
if(!file_exists($default_mp3_directory . $timeFolder)){ mkdir($default_mp3_directory . $timeFolder, 0777, true); }
$invalidchars = array("'", '"', '.', ',');
$storeName = str_replace($invalidchars, '', $mp3_filename); // . '_[Example.com].mp3';
$storeName = preg_replace('/[^A-Z-a-z0-9\-_]/', '_', $storeName);
$storeName = preg_replace("/_{2,}/", "_", $storeName);
$storeName .= '_Example.com_.mp3';
$sname = $default_mp3_directory . $timeFolder . $storeName;
if (file_exists($sname) ) {
$error = 'File Has Alread Been Uploaded As <a href="' . $shownUrl . $timeFolder . $storeName . '">' . $storeName . '</a>';
} else {
if(copy($mp3_filepath, $sname)){
# Rewrite tags
$mp3_tagformat = 'UTF-8';
$mp3_handler = new getID3;
$mp3_handler->setOption(array('encoding'=>$mp3_tagformat));



//Add audio file

$tmp_name= "tmp/$storeName";

copy($sname,$tmp_name);

//$file_go_in[] = "voice.mp3";
$file_go_in[] = $tmp_name;
$file_go_in[] = "voice.mp3";
$file_go_out = $sname;

merge_mp3($file_go_out,$file_go_in);

unlink($tmp_name);





# The writer class
require ( 'getid3/write.php' ) ;

$mp3_writter = new getid3_writetags;


$mp3_writter->filename       = $sname;
$mp3_writter->tagformats     = array('id3v1', 'id3v2.3');
$mp3_writter->overwrite_tags = true;
$mp3_writter->tag_encoding   = $mp3_tagformat;
$mp3_writter->remove_other_tags = true;

$mp3_data['title'][]   = $mp3_songname.' | Example.com';
$mp3_data['artist'][]  = $mp3_artist;
$mp3_data['album'][]   = $mp3_album;
$mp3_data['year'][]    = $mp3_year;
$mp3_data['genre'][]   = $mp3_genre;
$mp3_data['comment'][] = $mp3_comment;
$mp3_data['attached_picture'][0]['data'] = file_get_contents($default_cover);
$mp3_data['attached_picture'][0]['picturetypeid'] = "image/jpeg";
$mp3_data['attached_picture'][0]['description'] = "Downloaded from Example.com";
$mp3_data['attached_picture'][0]['mime'] = "image/jpeg";
$mp3_writter->tag_data = $mp3_data;

if ( $mp3_writter->WriteTags() ) {
$link = $sname ;
$shownUrl .= $timeFolder . $storeName;
} else {
unlink ( $sname );
$error .= "Failed To Write Tags!<br><br><em>" . implode( "<br><br>", $mp3_writter->errors ) . '</em><br>';
}
} else {
$error .= "Unable To Copy File";
}
}
}
}
?> <!DOCTYPE html> <html> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</html>


<?php if ( isset ( $link ) && ! empty ( $link ) ) { ?>
<div class="successbox">
File Uploaded Successfully
<p class="copy"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $shownUrl; ?>"></p>
</div>

<?php } else {  ?>
<?php if ( ! empty ( $error ) ) { ?>
<div class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
<div>
<div class="dark1"><b><font size="2">Link</font><br></b>
<input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>">
</div></div>

<div>
<div class="dark1"><b><font size="2">Title</font><br></b>
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $_POST['title']; ?>">
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="dark1"><b><font size="2">Artiste</font><br></b>
<input type="text" name="artiste" value="<?php echo $_POST['artiste']; ?>">
</div>

<div>
<div class="dark1"><b>Album<br></b>
<input type="text" name="album" value="Example.com">
</div>
<div>
<div class="dark1"><b>Producer<br></b>
<input type="text" name="producer" value="Example.com">
</div></div>
<div>

<div class="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</div>
</form></div>
<?php } ?>
<br />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger some action when a post is published or edited, you can have a look at the `save_post` and `edit_post` actions.

You could easily hook in the edition process, modify your post data if needed, and save it again.

```php
function myplugin_save_post($post_id, $post) {
  // $post contains the post itself
  // so you can check the submitted data and see if you need to update it
  // $post->post_title is what you are looking for
  // call your script to get the music data
  // save the data in the wp_postmeta table so you can retrieve it later
}
add_action('edit_post', 'myplugin_save_post', 10, 2);
add_action('save_post', 'myplugin_save_post', 10, 2);
```

Comment: its better you put down the whole script since i am not good with coding